# jQuery (Cheerio) not returning img src link

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a Javascript app for getting data off HTML pages.
With just text (titles, descriptions, etc.) it works fine, but for some reason trying to find the img src URL doesn't work.
My code is below, and below that are examples of what I've tried so far.

```
this.processDocument = function(html, url, headers, status, cheerio) {
            var app = this;
            var $ = cheerio;
            var $html = app.parseHtml(html, $);
    var object = {};

    object.title = $html.find('h1').text();
    object.title = this.removeExtraWhitespace(object.title);

    object.image = $html.find('.event_article').find('img').attr("src");

    object.copyright = $html.find('div[class="copyright"]').text();

    object.intro = $html.find('.introduction').text();
    object.intro = this.removeExtraWhitespace(object.intro);
    return JSON.stringify(object);
}
```

(examples of what I've tried)

```
object.image = $html.find('.event_article').find('img').attr("src");
object.image = $html.find('.event_article img').attr("src");
object.image = $('.event_article img').attr("src");
object.image = $('.event_article img').attr("src");
object.image = $html.find('.event_article img src').text();
object.image = $(unescape($html.find('.event-article').text())).find("img").attr("src");
object.image = $('figure').find('img').attr('src')
object.image = $html.find('figure').find('img').attr('src');
object.image = $html.find($('figure img')).attr('src');
```

(the HTML source code)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="contents_wrap">

    <!--main_contents------------------->
    <main role="main" id="main_contents">
        <div class="contents_inner">

            <!--event_article-->
            <section>
                <article class="event_article">
                    <h1 class="article_title">Bread & Coffee Party</h1>
                    <div class="info">
                        <figure class="image"><img src="https://d3cx2fdgbfj572.cloudfront.net/articles/images/000/025/392/small/a49553f4-5225-4b21-bbbb-c3c983648efb.jpg?1535574526" alt="breadandcoffee"><br><span class="copyright">John Hemberly</span></figure>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's a "lazy load" or AJAX image - if you view the HTML source of the page can you see the `<img>` element there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was in the end (tested for lazyload as well), but I took the image from another part of the page. The image was also mentioned in the 'content' meta tag at the head of the page so I got it from there.